# JDBC SQLite How to tell if database has active connections

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I've been trying to find a way to see if a database has active connections or not. I am using sqlite database with write ahead logging so I've been trying to check to see if the Wal file exists or not to determine if a database is active. (Specifically to see if it's actively being written to or not) Is there a more reliable way?

EDIT: This is a historical database. I use a failover functionality so a separate database while manipulating the main database. (Low end machine so manipulating a non actively writing database is quicker). So I'm trying to confirm that this database is freed up and the backup has begun writing. And then back again when switching back to the main.

Comment: You might do well to explain why this information is important to you. There may be other means of achieving your goals. There is also the possibility that you're barking up the wrong tree entirely.

Comment: MarsAtomic I updated the reasoning.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm trying to externally find this information out. To see if a writer is connected to a database or not.

Comment: Like the linked answer pointed out, you can't find that out directly via SQLite. Furthermore, you can't get the exact information you're after via external means either. The best you can do is the number of connections -- you cannot see whether those connections are in the process of writing.